Выберем трех, троих победителей или три победителя - вопрос по числительным
Помогите, пожалуйста, выбрать правильную форму числительного для предложения:
"Мы выберем трех (или троих) победителей". Или вообще: "Выберем три победителя".
Заранее спасибо!

Выберем трёх победителей.
Всё.
Можно и троих, конечно, выбрать, но, если употреблять собирательное числительное трое, надо, по-видимому, мыслить этих победителей как некую целостную группу.

Иногда пишут: выберите три человека. Почему? https://reshka.feniks.help/vysshaya-matematika/kombinatorika/iz-10-kandidatov-nuzhno-vybrat-3-cheloveka-na-konferenciju-skolkimi-razlichnymi-sposobami-jeto-mozhno-sdelat А если мыслить как целостную группу, то можно написать: для участия в региональных соревнованиях нужно выбрать троих победителей? Эта форма будет корректной?

Одушевлённое существительное в счётном обороте склоняют как неодушевлённое (винительный = именительный, а не родительный), потому что в рамках задачи "человеки" мыслятся как неодушевлённый абстрактый объект, подвергающийся математическим действиям, отсюда и неодушевлённость.
Сравните:
а) Я поймал (кого) трёх карасей (живые, отсюда одушевлённость); б) Мне принесли (что) три карася (карась - мясо, отсюда возможна и неодушевлённость);
а) Я арестовал (кого) трёх субъектов (людей); б) Рассмотрим (что) три синтаксических субъекта действия (то есть три подлежащих, отсюда неодушевлённость).

Это все понятно.  Но мы пишем: выбираем 3 человека. С цифрой иначе не напишешь, и этот вариант используется в разговорный  речи, хотя он некорректный.  Другой пример: надо выбрать двадцать три человека (форма В.п.). По-другому не скажешь. //  Двое ножниц. Не хватает двух ножниц. Нужна обязательная замена. Значит,  выбрать троих победителей  –  это тоже неверно? То есть нужна обязательная замена колич. числительным? //Другими словами, некорректным вариантам нужно обоснование.

Как это с цифрой не напишешь? Убью 3 человек.  Двадцать три человека - тут влияет числительное двадцать винительный = именительный. Троих победителей - тоже верно, как и трёх победителей.  У Герцена в "Былое и думы": "Я помню двоих крестьян средних лет, доползших, оставляя кровавый след, от границы до предместья, в котором жители подняли их полумертвыми".

Ну хорошо, убивайте 3 человек. Но запись все-таки странная, многие упорно пишут выберите 3 человека. А вот в составном числительном от В.п. не уйдешь, 23 человека и пишется, и звучит. (Числительное 20 не выражает категорию одушевленности.) Все это поддерживает неправильную форму. // В примере из Герцена вы видите целостную группу? А почему нет такой целостной группы в заданном вопросе? Выбор собир. или колич. числительного в косвенных падежах как-то связан со стилистикой или определяется только семантикой (целостная или нецелостная группа)?

Это  Валгина Н.С., Розенталь Д.Э., Фомина М.И. Современный русский язык: Учебник / Под редакцией Н.С. Валгиной  https://pedlib.ru/Books/6/0262/6_0262-258.shtml   Собирательные числительные мало употребительны при существительных в косвенных падежах и заменяются косвенными падежами соответствующих количественных числительных (двое студентов и два студента, но чаще - двум студентам, а не двоим студентам). Такая замена обычна при существительных, употребляемых только во множественном числе и сочетаемых с собирательными числительными (ср. двое суток - в течение двух суток).

Я не понимаю вас. Какая неправильная форма? Я убил трёх человек. Я убил троих человек. Всё. Обе формы  с одушевлённым существительным легитимны. Какая целостная или нецелостная группа? Я говорил о счётном обороте, и у Герцена именно такой счётный оборот с собирательным числительным и одушевлённым существительным. Форму выбрать три человека я не считаю неправильной, если под человеком понимается какой-о условный объект, объект математических действий. Предписания всяких Валгиных родом из 70 годов, и это капля в море исследований по синтаксису.

Тем не менне вы даете ответ: Выберем трёх победителей. Всё. // Вот и возникает вопрос: почему всё? // Если говорить о времени, то и Грамматика-80  тоже устарела.  А у Валгиной много книг, которые используются как учебники для студентов филологических специальностей вузов, и она доктор филологических наук. https://www.livelib.ru/author/3767/top-nina-valgina

Да я не отрицаю Валгину, просто русский язык - это не только Валгина. Кроме того, не думаю, что Грамматика-80 сильно устарела. До сих пор это самая лучшая и полная описательная грамматика русского языка. Уж точно она целостнее и научнее, чем творчество этих типов с "Русской корпусной грамматики" с их сентенциальными актантами, клаузами и прочим терминологическим недержанием.

Забавно! Но в корпусной грамматике  все-таки можно найти полезный практический материал по темам.  // Я  же всего лишь хотела узнать ваше мнение о стилистической и семантической оценке формы "троих победителей".   На слух эта форма действительно кажется  верной  хотя бы по стилю.
